# Problem in complex analysis .

Tags: complex-analysis

What are the theorems that I supposed use it to prove that :

> If $\mathcal f $  is entire and $\mathcal f(2z)=2f(z)$ then $ \exists $ $\lambda $ such that $\mathcal f(z)=\lambda\mathcal z
> $.

Comment: Also this self-deleted post from 30minutes ago  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1498770/problem-in-complex-analysis .   Do not re-ask closed questions without substantive change

Answer (score 3):

Another way. Let $\phi(z) = f(z)-f(1)z$. $\phi$ is entire.

Also, $\phi({1 \over 2^n}) = f({1 \over 2^n}) - f(1) {1 \over 2^n} = 0$.
Since the set of zeros has a limit point ($0$) we see that 
$\phi = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is entire, then $f$ can be written as a power series about $0$.  That is, we have
$$
f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k
$$
Now, note that
$$
f(2z) - 2f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (2^k - 2)a_k z^k
$$
All we need now is that the power series of an analytic function about $0$ is unique.

Answer (score 2):

Another way: From
$$f(z) = \frac {f(2z)} {2}\quad∀z ∈ ℂ,$$
you get $f’(z) = f’(2z)~∀ z ∈ ℂ$. From this, conclude that $f’$ is bounded. If $f$ is entire, then so is $f’$. Now use *Liouville*.

You can actually directly conclude from $f’(2z) = f’(z)$ that $f’$ is constantly $f’(0)$, only using the continuity of $f’$ at zero. You don’t need Liouville or anything else.

Comment: Neat!${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Why we conclude that derivative of f is bounded

Comment: @Fernando $f’$ is continuous, so it’s bounded on every compact set, including the compact closure of the unit disk. From $f’(z) = f’(2z)$ you can conclude that $f’(z) = f’(2^kz)$ for all $k ∈ ℤ$, so all values of $f’$ are already assumed by elements in the unit disk. But actually, for the continuity of $f’$ at zero, you already get $f’(z) = f’(0)$ for all $z ∈ ℂ$. You don’t need Liouville.